# image processing ideal LPF using matlab

Tags: matlab

I made ideal LPF, but result filter image doesn't exist.
Plz give me advice

```
I = rgb2gray(imread('testa.png'));

M = 512;

I = imresize(I, [M, M]);

[m, n] = size(I);

Ip = uint8(zeros(2*m, 2*n));

Ip(1:m,1:n) = double(I);

F = fft2(Ip);

D0 = round(M/10);

u = 0:2*M-1;

v = 0:2*M-1;

[u, v] = meshgrid(u,v);

D = sqrt( (u-((2*M+1)/2)).^2 + (v-((2*M+1)/2)).^2);

H = double(D <= D0);

G = H.*F;

g = ifft2(G);

subplot(2, 2, 1), imshow(I, []), title('Original Image');

subplot(2, 2, 2), imshow(log(1 + abs(fftshift(F))), []), title('Fourier Transform');

subplot(2, 2, 3), imshow(log(1 + abs((H))), []), title('Low-pass Filter');

subplot(2, 2, 4), imshow(real(g), []), title('Filtered Image');
```

Comment: You put the origin of the LPF in the middle of the array, but the FFT’s origin is on the top-left pixel. Use `ifftshift` to change your `H` to have the origin in the right place.

Comment: You can't implement an  ideal lowpass filter since its infinitely non-causal. Zeroing bins in the spectrum will give you sever time domain artifacts. This is not a good way to low pass filter (even if its done correctly).